# How to maximize a log linear regression equation satisfying a constraint?

Tags: python, linear-regression, optimization, excel, logarithmic

I have a log linear equation of the form $y = w_1(\log{X1}) + w_2(\log{X2}) + ... + w_n(\log{Xn})$.

How can I find the value of X's that maximize the value of y subject to a constraint $(X_1+X_2+...+X_n \le t)$ in python or excel?

I tried using Excel solver but ran into issues where one of the X variables became 0 in the process and gave undefined results.

Comment: Fair question: Should it not be the maximum with respect to w_i instead?And so the constrains should be fixed to w_i also

Comment: Julio, in this case, the regression model used X_i's as predictors to predict the value of Y_i. So, the value of w_i is constant (equal to coefficients from regressions) throughout